# What means "extended concepts of symmetry"?

Tags: reference-request, derived-algebraic-geometry, moduli-spaces

Where could one find a short description oft: "two mathematical extensions of the symmetry - to moduli spaces of sheaves and to derived categories", found [here](http://www.zib.de/de/mathematik-kalender.html?oid=98688)? Happen there interesting
things like with the moduli spaces of pointed curves etc.?

Comment: Presumably this is an attempt to work around the fact that the sporadic group $M_{24}$ appears to act on some structure underlying the elliptic genera of K3 surfaces (see Eguchi-Ooguri-Tachikawa), but does not actually act on the surfaces themselves.  Rather than explicitly constructing an object with $M_{24}$ symmetry, one may cheat and try to redefine the word "symmetry" (although I don't know a canonical choice of new definition).

Comment: Thanks Scott, but for me that passage sounds as if it wold refer to some new general principle, hmm... 